# Php function to separate a string at a fix position

Tags: php

Which PHP function can I use to separate the string `1stsemester` by inserting a space after the first three characters to turn it into `1st semester`?

I want to have the resulting string `1st semester` in a variable so that I can use it in a select statement.

Comment: What is the criteria used to determine where to separate the string? If you can't explain it, you can't program it.

Comment: Can the string be anything or does it have something defined?

Comment: IMO its should be pass or declare as it is required, so we don't need to change it in PHP script.
But if you still want the same behaviour then you can do using"

`$words = "1stsemester";   
 $word = substr_replace($words," ", 3, -strlen($words));`

Comment: Thank you Pintu Kumar. I will try this and get back to you. Barmar if I can recall,I never mentioned that I can program. No matter your level of programming experience. You are still a learner. Andreas the strings are already defined 1stsemester and 2ndsemester. The criteria for separation is the first 3 characters.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$words = "1stsemester";
$word = substr_replace($words," ", 3, -strlen($words));
```

Hope that solve your purpose.

Comment: We don't know what the question is yet. No reason to guess. Also your answer is very fixed and will only work with that specific string. OP needs to clarify the needs he has before we start guessing what he needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to represent a general solution which does not concern only to `1stsemester`. For that I'd use regular expression and this script will do the work.

```
preg_replace('/\d+(st|nd|rd|th)(?! )/i', '${0} ', $stringToCorrect);
```

this will make the following replacements in `$stringToCorrect` variable:

```
1stsemester => 1st semester
2ndquarter => 2nd quarter
3rdyear => 3rd year
4thwhatever => 4th whatever
57thmonth => 57th month
...
```